# Android - Shared Preferences crashes on some devices.

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have this exception that I get in my crash reports from Android:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.apply
at com.problemio.ProblemioActivity.first_time_check(ProblemioActivity.java:231)
at com.problemio.ProblemioActivity.onCreate(ProblemioActivity.java:47)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4668)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am pretty new to the crash reporting system in Android. Why would this crash happen? I can not reproduce it on my device or the simulator.

What other info is needed from the crash report to determine the cause and how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`apply()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29) was introduced in API level 9, and some devices that runs your app may be with lower version. consider changing this call to `commit`. As stated in the docs:

> The SharedPreferences.Editor interface isn't expected to be
>   implemented directly. However, if you previously did implement it and
>   are now getting errors about missing apply(), you can simply call
>   commit() from apply().

Comment: Thanks - I had commit before, but I remember it wasn't saving the data very persistently every time.  What is the good practice way of doing this so that I can make the data persist forever and also not crash?  Thanks!

Comment: If you had problems with `commit` it might be a good separate question, but as long as you support lower API levels you pretty much have to use commit...

Comment: thanks, in the documentation, what do they mean "you can call commit from apply?"

Comment: As I understand it, it should be **instead of**

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Look at the api version that it was started with.