# Declaring SharedPreferences.Editor crashes my app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
// I declared myPrefs globally in the lass  
SharedPreferences myPrefs = null;

// this is called in my do draw function
```

`public void doDraw() {

    myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();

    editor.putInt("MYHIGHSCORE", score);
    editor.commit();`
}

Whenever I call `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();`, my program crashes. What I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to store an int for a high score system. And `SharedPreferences` was suggested a lot for a mini high score system like mine.

Comment: what are the error messages?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy on the log cat it says that there is a nullpointer exception.

Comment: is your do draw function inside an Activity class then?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

```
package com.example.logindemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LoginPage extends Activity {

    EditText name = null, pwd = null;
    SharedPreferences login_pref = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_edt);
        pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd_edt);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void loginMethod(View v) {
        login_pref = this.getSharedPreferences("login_pref",
                MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor login_pref_editor = login_pref.edit();
        login_pref_editor.putString("Name", name.getText().toString());

        login_pref_editor.commit();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, WelcomeScreen.class));
    }
}
```

Try this. I think your shared pref object was not fetched properly.
Note: Edited post to add whole class's code.

Comment: sry, but by name("name".gettext().tostring()), what does it stand for?

Comment: That was my edittext. I have copied this line from my project. You will have to use whatever value you want to save in shared preference. I have put value of that edit text in shared preference with key "Name"

Comment: does that value apply to an int too?

Comment: so now my codes are `myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
  editor.putInt("MYHIGHSCORE", score);
  editor.commit();` but it still crashes. where score is an int value.

Comment: What is the exception? Still null pointer? And are you sure your SharedPreference object was declared as "myPrefs"?

Comment: yes its still a null pointer. And i declared my prefs correctly `SharedPreferences myPrefs = null;`

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8                            and java.lang.NullPointerException are the errors

Comment: Why have you used Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE instead of just MODE_WORLD_READABLE?

Comment: it gives an error, `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` cannot be resolved to a variable. and i saw from other samples that they used `Context.`

Comment: If your doDraw method is in activity only, it shouldn't give an error about MODE_WORLD_READABLE. Wait.I am adding my whole code in here.

Comment: i tink i 've got the issue. my dodraw is in a gameview class which is called at the activity class. that should be the reason why it crashes. how ever my score is retrieved from my gameactivity class. is there a way to get the value from my gameview class to the activity class?

Comment: You can pass value of score in gameview class's constructor.

Comment: Thanks alot for being patient with me. im not a good coder. tahnks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to have only one preference file, try to use this code to retrieve the `SharedPreference`.

```
myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is not at `edit()` but when u `apply()` your changes. Look at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491324/925202)

Comment: i use commit() instead of apply. just having `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();`. my app crashes.